# How do i create custom grid class in Bootstrap for lg as well as xs screen size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Here's the link to the page, check the columns.](http://edu4sure.com/edu4sure/welcome/view_detail_blog/57)
I have been working on CSS for a while and have felt dire need of custom size bootstrap columns. Please consider this situation, I have a two column design for the body of my website.

```
<body style="background-color : grey" style="padding-right : 2% ; padding-left : 2%">
<div class="row">
<div id="col1" class="col-lg-9 style="background-color : white">
<p> Some content here</p>
</div>
<div id="col2" class="col-lg-1" style="background-color : grey"></div>
<div id="col3" class="col-lg-2" style="background-color : white">
<p>Some content here for the right column</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Although, I want some space between the left major column and the right major column which is done by col2, the space is too much. If i style col2 with custom width the right column shifts along breaking the standard margin from right of 2% which is clearly visible because of my footer. Therefore i need to change the widths of both col2 as well as col3.

**I intend to use custom column class for lg screen size so that design stays intact on the mobile screen as well.**
*How do i create one? A short example would be appreciated*
Thank you

Comment: Can you please provide any working example or images of your desired output so we can try to help. Yes you can customise the bootstrap column without affecting the responsiveness.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning.
Done.

Comment: in given link which part you want to modify?

Comment: @Leo the lion 
Thanks for the quick reply, as you would have noticed the entire body is divided into two columns, the space between the left major column and right major column is col-lg-1 space. I want to reduce that space, without spoiling the design on mobile view.

Comment: well as far as i can see, this is not the correct way to give spacing. Why don't  you use float. well but in this case let me check.

Comment: you don't need to take extra div. Delete that and add col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 in md-3 div and  you will get that space. Remember there is offset property by which you can create gap without having extra div.

Comment: @Leo the lion
Did try that Leo but it is also giving a space of 1 grid column. I want the space to be around 3-4 %

Comment: try to increase the no or show me any image of desired output. I will try to create one for you. or you can change the width of that col-md-1. can't you?

Comment: See i can change the width of that column but the problem would be the design would shrink extremely in mobile view.  The link is the only place you could try anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to make a space between two Bootstrap columns (on the large screen only)

1. Remain only two columns.
2. Increase the `margin-left` of the right column.
3. Decrease the width of the right column by the same value.
4. Use `@media (min-width: 1200px)`.

Please check the result:

```css
/* heart of the matter */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  #col2 {
    margin-left: 4%;
    width: 21%; /* = 25% (width of .col-lg-3) - 4% (margin-left) */
  }
}

/* decorations */
* {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#col1, #col2, #header, #footer { 
  margin-top: 15px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
#col1, #col2     { background-color: #ccc; }
#header, #footer { background-color: #999; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="header" class="col-lg-12"> Header </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="col1" class="col-lg-9"> Main content </div>
    <div id="col2" class="col-lg-3"> Right column </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="footer" class="col-lg-12"> Footer </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gleb, it worked with few personalized changes. This is exactly what i was looking for so long. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Aman Glad to be of service! [Do accept my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped you.

Comment: Done mate, sorry for the delay. I am new to the community.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking is simply you want to display two columns on your body which your body design is basically contains.

Other than using customized css i think bootstrap has the in-build classes to show this in view.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body style="background-color : grey" style="padding-right : 2% ; padding-left : 2%">
<div class="row">
<div id="col1" class="col-lg-9 style="background-color : white">
<p> Some content here</p>
</div>
<div id="col2" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background-color : #e8e8e8">
                                                                                          <p>
           Some content goes here                                                        </p>
                                                                                  </div>
<div id="col3" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background-color : white">
<p>Some content here for the right column</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Just checkout the snippet here. ids which named col2,col3 are according to your requirements. I have changed the bg.color for an instance.
And, do some customization using css for the margin, padding and other style stuffs.
And, have a look on these bootstrap grid systems and read them. They'll get the idea how to do these.
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

And also you can make your web apps responsive using media queries.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Hope answered your question. Happy coding!

Comment: Hello Saiyaff,
 I am using second column for spacing between the two columns. I have added a link to make it clear. Please have a look.  Thank You.

Comment: That's not a good practice to add a column to divide two columns by adding one column unless you have content in it. You have css for that.

Comment: Why don't you remove that @Aman ? Cuz you can use it for the space using css. It's pretty much simple. When you build the site that's hard to figure out what's the best practice. Yeah it's better to learn while doing. The knowledge by the experience is real insight...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Saiyaff, would keep that in mind from next time.
I tried using offset although that is also giving a lot of space between the columns.

Comment: Did you tried writing css. Customizing the bootstrap thing by css?

Comment: Yes Saiyaff, I did. Although, that breaks the design in mobile view. Thats why i am attempting to create custom lg and xs class for the right column.

Comment: "that breaks the design in mobile view" Yeah that happens. That's why there are media queries... Checked my answer. there is a link about css media queries. Got it?

Comment: Yes I did. I was seeking an answer though because i failed to add a custom class only for media query. Either way thanks. Will look into it.

Comment: You don't wanna add a custom class to write media query. you already have an id declared. or if you wanna apply the media query for the set of components use a common class.

Comment: I have marked the answer Farouk, thats exactly what i was seeking. Thanks for the help :)